# Modify permission of a moved file in unix

Tags: unix, find, chmod

I am moving a file from my server storage area to NAS (network attached storage).
The move command is in my script and executed daily. As :-

```
find . \ -mtime +0 -exec mv {} target \ ;
```

From my knowledge above command is supposed to move files modified last between 24hrs and 48hrs.By default the file moved gets permission of 64 . Now i wanted to change permission to 644 for these moved files. Note that file is moved from server to NAS. I added the below command in script

```
find target \ -mtime 0 -exec chmod 644 {}  \ ;
```

Note the 0 and not +0 in above command .But this does not seem to work . Is it because due -mtime +0 means last modified b/w 24hr and 48hr and that is retained when file is moved from server to NAS. what would be the appropiate mtime value to be provided by me in this case . I know a simple way out may be to give it as `mtime -3` which will modify permission for all files modified less than 72 hrs . But i do not want this command to run over all 3 days of moved files but just on one which has been moved via my command 
`find . \ -mtime +0 -exec mv {} target \ ;`

Comment: Do you only expect to `find` files? Adding `-type f` is more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the backslashes.
Your find copies all files to one target folder.
When you are OK with that, (and have write rights in all dirs) you can do

```
find . -mtime +0 -exec chmod 644 {} \; -exec mv {} target \;
```

You have more control for simple dirs/files (without spaces/other special chars) with

```
find . -mtime +0 | while read file; do
   filename=${file##*}
   mv ${file} ${target}
   chmod 644 ${target}/${filename}
done
```

Comment: my bigger concern here is difference or impact of mtime when file is copied and when they are moved. Do you mean that when a file is moved their permissions are preserved ? In that case you make sense ..but cant we do it simply as i am doing it .

Comment: Permissions are preserved except for special bits (setguid, ..). I do not want to play with time (does the NAS have the same timezone? Sync?) .
Most of all, I want to use `find` only once. I did not test your solution.

Comment: find . -mtime +0 -exec chmod 644 {} \; -exec mv {} target \; is probably not the best way to do it as it would try and change permission for all files older than 24hr and will be repetitive. I guess the more appropriate solution should have been  find . -mtime -2 -exec chmod 644 {} \; -exec mv {} target \; which makes sure that chmod is executed only files modified in less than 48 hrs and hence does not repeat it operation daily on the file which has been moved there before 48hrs.